# CiviCRM uses mail server account address as sender

Tags: email

I log in as a user of CiviCRM.
I then go to a contact and send an email as activity. Even if my mail address is shown as sender in the mail, when the mail is recieved - the sender is the account used to log in to the mail server (GMail). It seemingly does not use "By default, CiviCRM uses the primary email address of the logged in user as the FROM address when sending emails to contacts. "

How do I keep my CiviCRM user mailaddress as the sender on the recieving end?

Comment: It seems to be a GMail thing. Using a mail relay, preserves the original sending mail address.

Answer (score 2):

As Martin said, this would appear to be a gmail thing.

I know that gmail accounts can be configured to send email on behalf of other accounts. If you were able to set that up gmail settings, it might allow you to send on behalf of that person.